# What were the suits in the pack of cards used in Sherlock Holmes Game of Shadows

Tags: analysis, sherlock-holmes-a-game-of-shadows

This pack of cards is owned by the fortune teller. It includes the Two of Cups, The Fool and The Devil.

[image]

When was this version of cards in common use?

Comment: The card to the right is Temperance and not the Devil.

Comment: @Ken the devil appears later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are tarot cards. They look like an original Oswald Wirth tarot deck. This deck would have been used in 1889 or possibly 1926, when the cards were redrawn.

Source: https://marygreer.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/oswald-wirth-meets-sherlock-holmes/